# W3 Total Cache not rewriting URLs for files cached on AWS-based CDN

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, minify, amazon-cloudfront, w3-total-cache

I am using W3 Total Cache plugin, the plugin is set up to work with AWS-based CDN (S3+CloudFront):

1. Minify CSS and JS files
2. Send them to AWS's S3
3. S3 sends them to AWS's CloudFront

The process above seems to work fine:

- `style.css` gets minified as `18704.css` and
- `script.js` gets minified as `39633.js`.
- Automatic upload into the CDN works, I can then manually access the files by typing the URLs into the address bar in the browser:

  - **S3 URL** e.g. `https://<instance>.amazonaws.com/wordpress/wp-content/cache/minify/1/39633.js` gets found and
  - **CloudFront URL** e.g. `https://<distribution_id>.cloudfront.net/wp-content/cache/minify/1/39633.js` gets found

The automatic URL rewrite by the plugin (when loading a webpage) is what most likely fails, because the HTML header still has the **original hostname** in the URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/cache/minify/1/39633.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/cache/minify/1/18704.css" media="all" />
```

Why does the W3 Total Cache plugin **not rewrite** the URLs with CloudFront as the host?

Chrome's network console: The minified files get pulled from the original host and not the CDN

[image: The minified files get pulled from the original host and not the CDN]

POSSIBLE WORKAROUND:

This seems like a workaround, but it works. By specifying RewriteRules in `.htaccess` file I force the site to load `.css` and `.js` files via the CDN.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^ https://<distribution_id>.cloudfront.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But there is still one files that resists to be redirected (`18704.css`). I have my browser cache turned off (even deleted browser cache manually) and the file still resists to be loaded from cache. I think this has nothing to do with browser caching, Chrome's network console says the file is not loaded from cache.

[image: 18704.css]

Answer (score 1):

What you need to is to set the minify option to manual and then upload the minify file with w3total cache. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6ZHG.png)